# GoogleTagManager do not seem to accept base64 encoded picture

Tags: javascript, image, base64, google-tag-manager

Is it me or GoogleTagManager do not seem to accept base64 encoded pictures?
Exemple with the very basic code below with a very basic image.

I get the following error : 
- Type : JavaScript Too Long"
- Description :
"The JavaScript in your Arbitrary HTML tag has too many contiguous non-whitespace characters (e.g. an array literal '[1,2,..]' that is too long). Try inserting spaces between statements to allow compilation (e.g. change '[1,2,...]' to '[1, 2, ...]')."

Is there no way to implement this in GTM, beside putting the js somewhere else than directly into GTM?

Best,
J.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myurl = "http://wwww.toto.com";
        var myimg = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
        $("#beta-ad").empty();
        $('<div/>', { id: "1" }).insertBefore($("#beta-ad"));
        $("#1").append('<a href=" ' + myurl + ' " target="_blank"><img src="' + myimg + '" style="display:inline; width: auto;" ></img></a>')
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to contact Google support for this. There is no direct way to store such a long base64 string right now in GTM

Comment: Thanks Tushar for the reply. I indeed created a thread in the Google Tag manager board just in case...

Comment: Oki i will ask the devs directly... will post as soon as i get the response 

Comment: If it's problem with declaring such a long string in HTML maybe you can simply break it into smaller parts? e.g. "var myimg = "longstring"; myimg += "anotherlongstring" ???

Comment: Hello @Matus i have thought of that, but it's not really satisfying. The given code is a VERY basic b64 encoded picture.
I was actually trying to use another one which if I remember correctly was doing something like 60,000 caracters. If i have to split in 600x100 caracters, it's not gonna be fun...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by design. But the workaround proposed by @Matus works.

To get around the issue of having to generate JS for a very long base base 64 encoded string I wrote a utility function, splitting the string into chunks of 150 (which GTM accepts), and generating the JS concatenation code.

You can then drop this code into your GTM tag, and reference the base64 variable.

```
function splitString(string, size, multiline) {
  var matchAllToken = (multiline == true) ? '[^]' : '.';
  var re = new RegExp(matchAllToken + '{1,' + size + '}', 'g');
  var responses = string.match(re);
  var value = "var base64='';";
  responses.forEach(response => {
    value += "base64+='" + response + "';";

  });
  return value;
}

var base64 = 'eyJ3aWRnZXRfc2.... etc';

var gtmString = splitString(base64, 150, true);

console.log(gtmString);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azqpdwxg/2/

Comment: Thanks for that! 
I will try it, next time I want to do that !